# How do I recover contact from android phone(one plus one) after touchscreen stopped working?

Tags: broken-screen, oneplus-one

I dropped my phone, and the touch screen stopped working. So, I can't access the phone. The phone is practically useless besides looking at the time. Is there a dongle that I can use to control the phone externally like a pc? Or any other way to recover my contacts from the cellphone, besides actually fixing it?

I want to get a new phone, and don't want to spend money on fixing it.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! May I recommend you taking a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) – which holds pointers for this issue as well as other stuff related to, ahem, problems with a broken/unresponsive screen? Especially a look at its "data recovery" section will prove helpful I guess :)

Comment: Did your phone was connected to google services?

Answer (score 1):

If only touch stopped working and screen is properly visible then you could try the USB OTG with keyboard and mouse to go to contacts app and export your contact or sync them to google account

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb commands for touching your phone.

The command for touching the screen is:

```
adb shell input touchscreen tap x y
```

For more information about the adb you can read here:
http://adbshell.com/

Good lack!